# How to perform Redo Undo operation in EditText

Tags: android

I want to know is there any method or any link or tutorial to perform redo undo operation in Android edittext. If any one knows than please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

Quick note on the [Antti-Brax](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6458#c123)/[Divers(Kidinov](https://gist.github.com/kidinov/6900164#file-undo_redo-android)) solution.  It works great, except if you try to use it with a TextView post-API 23, you'll run into problems, because guess-what, Google actually added a hidden [UndoManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+log/master/core/java/android/content/UndoManager.java) (android.content.UndoManager) and didn't document it or make it obvious it was there.  But if you have a hard/bluetooth keyboard in Marshmallow or Nougat and hit ^Z or SHIFT-^Z, you'll get undo/redo.

The problem comes if you're already using Antti-Brax's class with an EditText, and you also hook it to ^Z and shift-^Z, you'll run into problems with anyone using a hard keyboard.  Namely the ^Z will trigger BOTH the native and Antti-Brax's undo, leading to two undos simultaneously, which isn't good.  And after a few of them, you'll probably get a Spannable out of bounds crash.

A possible solution I found is to subclass the TextView/TextEdit/whatever and intercept the undo/redo calls from the TextView so they don't run as follows:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTextContextMenuItem(int id) {
        int ID_UNDO, ID_REDO;

        try {
            ID_UNDO = android.R.id.undo;
            ID_REDO = android.R.id.redo;
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            ID_UNDO = 16908338; // 0x1020032
            ID_REDO = 16908339; // 0x1020033
        }
        return !((id == ID_UNDO) || (id == ID_REDO)) && super.onTextContextMenuItem(id);
    }
```

Those magic id numbers were found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/f59152cf00520d1bd36949b44faca2e1fcf6d28f%5E%21/#F7), and are used only as a backup if the android.R.id.undo values aren't found.  (it also might be reasonable to assume that if the values aren't there the feature isn't there, but anyway...)

This is not the best solution because both undo trackers are still there and both are running in the background.  But at least you won't trigger both of them simultaneously with ^Z.  It's the best I could think to do until this gets officially documented and the getUndoManager() methods of TextView is no longer hidden...

Why they made a feature you can't turn off (or even know if it was there or not) "live" in released Android I can't say.

I just opened an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221679) on Android's issue tracker if anyone wants to follow this.

Answer (score 3):

There is an implementation of undo/redo for Android EditText in 
http://credentiality-android-scripting.googlecode.com/hg/android/ScriptingLayerForAndroid/src/com/googlecode/android_scripting/activity/ScriptEditor.java

The code works but does not handle configuration changes properly. I am working on a fix and will post here when it is complete.

My Google search was :-
android edittext onTextChanged undo

Comment: Thanks For Reply i will be trying it and replying you soon

Comment: The link in the answer no longer exists there.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but as there is no accepted answer, and this is an issue I've tackled myself from many angles, I'd like to add my solution in case it helps anyone. My answer is probably most relevant to large (1,000words+) volumes of text editing apps that require this feature.

The simplest way to resolve this problem is to make periodic copies of all text on screen, save it to an array and call `setText()` every time the Undo method is called. This makes for a reliable system, but it isn't ideal for large (i.e. 1,000words+) text editing apps. This is because it:

- Is wasteful. It could be that only one word changes in a two thousand word document, so that's one thousand, nine hundred and ninety nine words needlessly committed to memory.
- Can lead to performance issues, as some low-tier hardware struggles with rendering large amounts of text. On some of my test devices, this method can lead to freezes of a few seconds whenever Undo is called.

The solution I currently use is comparatively complex, but I've published the results in a [library here](https://github.com/PPartisan/RunDo).

Essentially, this library saves a copy of text as soon as a user begins typing, and then another copy of text once they've stopped typing for a set amount of time (in my case, two seconds). The two text strings are then compared, and the altered section of text returned, the indexes where the alterations occured, and details on whether or not the change was an addition of new text, a deletion, or a replacement of old text with new text.

The net result is that only the necessary text is saved, and when Undo is called, there is only a local `delete()`, `replace()` or `insert()` call, which makes for much faster operations on large text fields.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the undo/redo implementation that was linked to from Gary Phillips' answer extracted into a reusable and universal undo/redo plugin for any widget that descends from a TextView. I added some code for persisting the undo history.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6458#c123

Hope this helps.

Comment: I extend it with "batches" functionality. Can be find there - https://gist.github.com/kidinov/6900164#file-undo_redo-android

Comment: Does this also preserve styling (bold italic etc...)?

Comment: @Mike The text stored in the edit history is represented as CharSequence objects. I haven't done any work with styled text on Android but I would assume that all styling will be lost, since CharSequence only stores characters, not any styling information. Please try and report your findings.

Comment: I didn't test your code with styles, I ended going a different route. I'll post my answer...

Answer (score 1):

To preserve EditText Styling with regards to undo: 
You can create an `ArrayList<EditText>` or  `ArrayList<String>` (String containing html text)  to store your last 10 (for example) actions. So ArrayList [0] would contain html text from your *first* action and `ArrayList [9]` would contain html text from your very *last* action. Each time the user taps "undo" in your app, you would apply `ArrayList [size()-1]`  to your EditText and then remove ArrayList [size()-1]  from your Array.